# Team member does not show on "Assign to" on work items in vs team servies

Tags: azure-devops

I have added a user, in the Work Iterations,  I can see him in the Capacity but he does not show in the "Assign To" selection for work items.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found how.

just enter the name and select "Search" :-)

Comment: Search is fine, but it will be much better if team members show up in "Assign to".  How can we make it show up automatically?